# Why does a Kutit child who had sexual relationship with a Jew deserve death?

Tags: gentiles, capital-punishment

I found this link online but found nothing else similar to it anywhere else. I attempted to ask a rabbi who outright refused to read the link and explain it so I’m even more confused.

Rambam, [the Laws of Forbidden Relationships 12:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.12.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אֲבָל יִשְׂרָאֵל הַבָּא עַל הַכּוּתִית בֵּין קְטַנָּה בַּת שָׁלֹשׁ שָׁנִים וְיוֹם אֶחָד בֵּין גְּדוֹלָה בֵּין פְּנוּיָה בֵּין אֵשֶׁת אִישׁ וַאֲפִלּוּ הָיָה קָטָן בֶּן תֵּשַׁע שָׁנִים וְיוֹם אֶחָד כֵּיוָן שֶׁבָּא עַל הַכּוּתִית בְּזָדוֹן הֲרֵי זוֹ נֶהֱרֶגֶת מִפְּנֵי שֶׁבָּא לְיִשְׂרָאֵל תַּקָּלָה עַל יָדֶיהָ כִּבְהֵמָה. וְדָבָר זֶה מְפֹרָשׁ בַּתּוֹרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (במדבר לא טז) "הֵן הֵנָּה הָיוּ לִבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל בִּדְבַר בִּלְעָם" (במדבר לא יז) "וְכָל אִשָּׁה יֹדַעַת אִישׁ לְמִשְׁכַּב זָכָר הֲרֹגוּ":

> If a Jewish man has relations with a gentile girl, irrespective of whether she is three years and one day old or if she is an adult, married or unmarried, even if the male is nine years and one day old - since he has deliberately had relations with a gentile - the girl is killed - for the sin of a jew has be perpetrated because of her. This ruling is explicitly stated in the Torah, as it says, "Yet they are the very ones who, at the bidding of Balaam, induced the Israelites to trespass against the LORD in the matter of Peor...and also slay every woman who has known a man carnally."

See the discussion [here](https://malimaalah.wixsite.com/offthederechthoughts/amp/the-raped-child-the-halacha-to-kill-a-non-jewish-rape-victim).

After reading the link I was wondering if this is accurate why not just excommunicate a non-Jew but kill them?

Can anyone explain how this is justified, G-d is all loving but this doesn’t seem like it.

Comment: Welcome to hardcore Judaism, Jewishboy, it might be different from what you're used to. It also works differently: in the Talmud, rabbis occupy themself with interpreting Biblical verses according to their imagination. Sometimes it takes unexpected turns, and comparing gentiles to animals is one of them. Once you've equaled them, the resulting Halachah is straightforward, and nothing Rambam can help with: just like a subject of bestiality is killed, so is a gentile.

Comment: ... *continued* For ages, many Halochos remain purely theoretical, and rabbis dealt with them hypothetically, "just because" they are there, trying to justify them retroactively (Jewish apologetics). You should not make such a fuss, but rather understand that this is how the Halachah works.

Comment: There is a broader question that may potentially come into play here, and that is the severity of killing non-jews. On this score, the Rambam (Avodah Zarah 10:1) is shockingly lenient, while other rishonim, specifically Tosfos (Avodah Zarah 26b s.v. ולא), are stringent. It could be that the Rambam is simply following his own shitah and that such a woman would be in the same category as apikorsim and mosrim, or perhaps it's like sha'as milchama. But this is all speculation. See the Ma'aseh Roke'ach on the Rambam mentioned in the question.

Comment: It is not explicitly written, but he was speaking on the case that Kutit tried to seduce the man, and therefore she deserves a punishment. This is the reason he compares it to Midyan, because the women were not innocent, rather they actively seduced the Israelites.

Answer (score 4):

Not all versions of the Rambam actually have that halacha but we will put that aside because many sources do discuss it. Nowhere does the Rambam say that he is referring to a rape victim. The source it is based on  (milchomes midyan) was not a case of rape but rather a case of seduction. As I recall only one of the commentaries on the Rambam (written less than a hundred years ago)  even considers that as a possibility. Even  he comes to the conclusion that the Rambam was not referring to such a case.

As far as why not just excommunicate the non-Jew. Would that have any effect? Many of the later commentators say that the Rambam is not referring to a case of a  Ger Toshev who accepts the authority of Torah and practices Noahide laws . Someone living in Eretz Yisroel, under Jewish rule, when the Beis Hamkdash was standing (the only time this law could have been carried out) and still refuses to  be a Ger Toshev probably wouldn't be impressed with anything other than the knowledge of a law on the books that such behavior could be a capital crime.

The guy in the discussion is badly misquoting both the Igros Moshe and the Minchas Chinuch (as well as butchering and distorting  MANY  other halachos. Someone who raped a child would receive makkas mardos which is given without prior warning,  see the Ran, in his commentary on the Rif on Kesubos (16b in Old Rif pages)etc. etc. etc.

The guy correctly understands the Igros Moshe as saying the reason the women is killed is due to kanoim pogin bo but he badly distorts both what Rav Moshe says about this case  and the general halachos involved in kanoim pogin bo. Firstly unlike this guy's fantasy scenario Beis Din never gets personally involved in a case where someone is killed due to kanoim pogin bo. Not only that  if someone were to ask in Beis Din if they should kill the people involved they would be told NOT to. Thirdly kanoim pogin bo is not a blanket hetter for anyone to kill someone engaged in such behavior. It is limited to someone who has the status of a "kanoi" It also would require a situation where the act was done publicly in front of ten people (Rav Moshe is uncertain that applies here) . Nowhere does Rav Moshe imply he was discussing a case of rape.

He distorts  the Minchas Chinuch even worse because the Minchas Chinuch pretty clearly says this would NOT refer to a case of rape. The Minchas Chinuch ends by saying that must be according to  the opinion of the Rambam that a child has the mental capacity agree to sexual relation (without it being considered rape)

The Gemora Kesubos and elsewhere says that seducing a child is in the category of rape. Many commentators ask on the Rambam how he can say otherwise. The standard answer is that it is a sexual act in relation to general laws that the act affects but not in relation to the personal liability of the child.

Furthermore in general   the concept “child” is misleading for the unlearned audience the guy in the link is writing for. It is true that by non-Jews there is no concept of being Bar – Bas Mitzvah. Therefore age is not a factor in Beis Din. What IS a factor is maturity and consciousness of wrong doing. A non-Jewish child brought to Beis Din who was too young to understand that what they were doing is wrong would not be held responsible for their behavior.

There is much more to be said on this topic but it is beyond the scope of a stack exchange answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea who wrote that or why, but it's ridiculous. The Torah spells out quite clearly that we don't blame rape victims.

Comment: It's explicit in the rambam. No one is blaming anyone

Comment: @DoubleAA ah sorry -- based on the sugya in Sanhedrin about kalon, right.